# Disk apparently full despite only ~25% being reported in baobab

Tags: 18.04, disk, disk-usage

### The problem

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 and have an encrypted home folder.

I am having this weird problem where baobab only reports on ~95GB of my data, whereas `df -h` tells me my Ubuntu partition has 480GB with a usage of 100%.

The usage of 100% is something I cannot explain, but bothers me a lot and creates problems.

My home directory, with ~78GB (reported by baobab), makes up for most of the 95GB mentioned above.

I don't really know how to proceed from here. Please help me find out what is going on and where 75% of disk usage come from that I cannot account for.

### Appendix

#### `df -x squashfs -x tmpfs -h -T`

```
Filesystem               Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                     devtmpfs   16G     0   16G   0% /dev
/dev/nvme0n1p7           ext4      480G  447G  8.7G  99% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1           vfat      646M   77M  570M  12% /boot/efi
/home/sebastian/.Private ecryptfs  480G  447G  8.7G  99% /home/sebastian
```

#### `sudo du -hs /* | sort -h`

```
0       /initrd.img
0       /initrd.img.old
0       /proc
0       /sys
0       /vmlinuz
0       /vmlinuz.old
4.0K    /cdrom
4.0K    /lib64
4.0K    /srv
16K     /lost+found
40K     /media
48K     /dev
176K    /root
3.0M    /tmp
3.2M    /run
5.8M    /lib32
6.5M    /libx32
13M     /sbin
14M     /bin
21M     /etc
234M    /boot
516M    /mnt
848M    /lib
1.2G    /opt
6.5G    /usr
12G     /snap
146G    /home
712G    /var
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your post and add the output of `sudo du -hs /* | sort -h`? It might complain about inaccessible `/proc` and `/run` directories which you can simply ignore.

Comment: @PerlDuck Edited and posted output. Where do the 712GB come from in `/var`, do you have any clue? And why is the reported `/home` here almost double in size?

Comment: Weird. Can you please also replace the output of your `df -h` with the output of `df -x squashfs -x tmpfs -h -T`? That omits the "uninteresting" file systems.

Comment: @PerlDuck also done. I don't exactly know where these "new" 7GB come from. The only thing I did in the meantime was starting docker.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder how your `/var` can use 712 GB when the `/` filesystem has a size of "only" 480 GB. Actually I currently have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reboot, because it got so bad. So I had to investigate further.

Okay, so as it turns out the file system was actually full. Why it didn't appear in the lists, I have no idea.

The problem was the PHP xdebug profiler running in a docker container writing the whole filesystem full with the profiling files (`cachegrind.out.*`).

How I found this out:

booting up in recovery mode, opening the root shell. `telinit 2`, login (maybe this step is not necessary, I don't know). Then run `du -hs /* | sort -h` and finding out that under `/var` is the actual culprit (this time with "only" 306G usage, which seemed more likely). Running the `du` command a couple of more times to find out that the files in a `/tmp` folder of a docker container that I was running were writing the disk full. So the solution was to delete all these files and reboot and voila the system rebooted as normal and I'm back to 22% disk usage.